# Android notification with GCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have chat app with GCM. When app is in foreground on particular chat activity i don't want to receive or show this notification. How i can do that?

Here is my notification:

```
private void sendNotification(String message, String userId, String senderName) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChatActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.putExtra("userId2", userId);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(senderName+" send message")
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check whether ChatActivity is in foreground or not keep one variable.
`boolean isActive;` make this variable `false` in `onPause` and `onDestroy` and make it `true` in `onResume`. For accessing this variable in other class make it `public` and `static` to access it with class name.

```html
public static boolean isActive;

@Override
public void onResume() {
 super.onResume();
 isActive=true;
}
@Override
public void onPause() {
 super.onPause();
 isActive=false;
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
 super.onDestroy();
 isActive=false;
}
```

Now while sending notificaton check value of this variable.

```html
if(!ChatActivity.isActive){
  sendNotification();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can unregister GCM when your app in in foreground or save app state on SharedPreference.

Comment: i have many chat rooms, i don't want get push only from foreground chat room

Answer (score 0):

You can check wheather is your app is in forground or not by this

;

```
import java.util.List;

import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class ForegroundCheckTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Context... params) {
        final Context context = params[0].getApplicationContext();
        return isAppOnForeground(context);
    }

    private boolean isAppOnForeground(Context context) {
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<RunningAppProcessInfo> appProcesses = activityManager
                .getRunningAppProcesses();
        if (appProcesses == null) {
            return false;
        }
        final String packageName = context.getPackageName();
        for (RunningAppProcessInfo appProcess : appProcesses) {
            if (appProcess.importance == RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND
                    && appProcess.processName.equals(packageName)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And add this permission in you manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
```

Comment: that permission is deprecated